# i want display result from CMD to IRC

Tags: perl, command, cmd, irc

i want display result from CMD to IRC with Perl

Example (input command from IRC) :

```
!cmd dir C:\
```

Result (Display to IRC) :

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
11/11/2011  00:00 AM    <DIR>   Program file
11/11/2011  00:00 AM    <DIR>   aaa.txt
11/11/2011  00:00 AM    <DIR>   bbb.exe
```

Comment: And what part of this are you having trouble with?  Stack Overflow isn't a "please write my program for me" site.

Comment: As an IRC client extension? As a bot? As an extension to an IRC server?

Comment: This code for my irc bot
`
http://pastebin.com/TydVxz0x
`

`
@result=qx($cmd);
foreach(@result){
 print $connect "PRIVMSG ",$channel," :@result\r\n";
}
`

this code can't display all result,
but show this
"Volume in drive C has no label."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this this using [AnyEvent::IRC](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aIRC), [POE::Component::IRC](https://metacpan.org/module/POE%3a%3aComponent%3a%3aIRC) or their subclasses/descadents.

Both packages are pretty documented, but prepare to implement basic actions and events:

1. Connect to server
2. Join a channel
3. Handle all messages in channel (or private messages) and respond with your result.

Comment: in particular, Bot::BasicBot::Pluggable is nice

Comment: `Bot::BasicBot::Pluggable` also based on `POE::Component::IRC`, but my opinion is that it has too much dependencies for such similar task. DBI? CGI? XML::Feed? Just to connect IRC and send output of command?

Comment: I'm assuming the question is how to listen for a command, run it on the client, and put the results in the channel.  That's harder.  If it were just piping stuff to IRC, I'd start with sirc.

Comment: @ysth I assume you mean "listen for a command in channel/person on IRC". If so, basic prototype for functionality you described should fit in 150-200 LOC and 1H of very lazy copypasting code samples into a text editor. But I might misunderstand you.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.  for comparison, a B::BB::P module would be about a dozen lines, most of them package/sub/var declaration